# Using colon syntax and variables in Sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, haml, sass

I am still using the old colon syntax (I prefer it more than the 
bracket syntax) and this particular code:

```
a.button-link 
  +box($main-color) 
  +border-radius(5px) 
  :background 
    :color $main-color 
  :color #fff 
  :padding 5px
```

generates a warning like so:

DEPRECATION WARNING: 
On line 12, character 3 of '/Users/eumir/rails_apps/dxconnect/app/ 
stylesheets/partials/utilities/_link-styles.sass' 
Setting properties with = has been deprecated and will be removed in 
version 3.2. 
Use "background: $main-color" instead.

I tried that but my background color still doesn't show up. Any help 
on this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working answer I got from the Haml groups. Apparently I declared my variable as $main-color: "#f00" instead of just $main-color: #f00

"Your $main-color variable shouldn't have quotes. In Sass 3, all variables 
and mixin arguments should be just as you want them to appear in the CSS, 
without any extra quotes. "

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a.button-link
  background: $main-color
```

or

```
a.button-link
  background-color: $main-color
```

Comment: yup i tried that already. it doesn't work(sass compiles right but it doesn't generate the one with no preceding colon

Answer (score 1):

Even if you prefer the SASS syntax instead of SCSS (I do too!), you should update your files using the converter:

```
sass-convert --from=sass2 --to=sass --recursive views/stylesheets
```

See `sass-convert --help` for all the options options.

Comment: but updating them means ill be seeing scss files when i edit them right?

Comment: No, you will get SASS files, if you use the --to=sass option.