# What is this odd SASS property syntax?

Tags: ruby, sass

I'm working with some SASS code, written for ruby-sass v3.2. In some of the stylesheets, property declarations are written like:

```
.something
  :height 10em
  :width 100%
  :font-size 1.5em
```

This compiles and appears to be valid, but I can't find reference to it anywhere. Is this just a quirk of Ruby parsing them as symbols, or something in SASS I've never seen before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150208082452/http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html) to find the "official" information, and it seems that it is just the old SASS way to write a declaration:

> #### Property Syntax
>
> The indented syntax supports two ways of declaring CSS
>   properties. The first is just like CSS, except without the semicolon.
>   The second, however, places the colon before the property name. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> #main
>   :color blue
>   :font-size 0.3em
> ```
>
> By default, both ways may be used. However, the [:property_syntax option](https://web.archive.org/web/20150207060610/http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#property_syntax-option) may be used to specify that
>   only one property syntax is allowed.

I also found some others mentions of this syntax here:

- [Using colon syntax and variables in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3062241/9718056)
- [Convert Sass stylesheets from the old colon syntax](https://gist.github.com/aarongray/7376335)
- [Deprecate old-style property syntax](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2245)

---

**Edit** : there is also an online reference about this [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/sass-syntax).

Comment: Excellent detective work, thank you! I assumed it was something like this, but I'd never seen it (and I've been using SASS for close to 10 years). What an odd convention - I wonder what the rationale behind it was.

Comment: You're welcome, I actually enjoyed to look for that information!